# Why is Python 2.7 faster than 3.2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I wrote the following program as a solution to Project Euler problem 12 but in Python 2.7 it takes 6.62 seconds and in Python 3.2 it takes 10.21 seconds. Surely it should be the other way round!

```
import time

def mainrun():
    start = time.time()
    divnum = 0
    i = 0
    trinum = 0
    while divnum < 501:
        i += 1
        trinum += i
        divnum = 0
        #2nd arg outside - no diff to speed 
        for j in range(1, int(trinum**.5)+1):
            if trinum % j == 0:
                divnum += 1
                if trinum / j != j:
                    divnum += 1
    print(trinum, '\nDivisors:', divnum)
    print('Solved in', round((time.time()-start),2), 'seconds.')

mainrun()
```

Does anyone know why the later version of Python is slower?

Comment: Use `timeit` to compare code snippets to minimize the influence of other OS events (disk I/O flushes, for example) and garbage collection.

Comment: Why are you comparing to Python 3.2 and not the latest?

Comment: The timings are consistent and I'm on a Chromebook so there's no hard disk.

Comment: @thebjorn comparing 2.7 against 3.4 I get 3.25s and 6.4s respectively. Using integer division makes no measurable difference.

Comment: I timed this with `timeit.repeat`, and got the following relative times: `{'2.7.6': 1.00, '3.2.3': 1.47, '3.3.5': 1.54, '3.4.0': 1.70}`.

Comment: Does that mean that the 3.x line is getting increasingly slower..?

Comment: @eryksun if we want to consider all things, then consider that the 2.x line got faster and faster. I'm starting to wonder why I would want to transition my 160Kloc of 2.7 code to 3.x if all I can expect is 70% slower execution speed and more annoying syntax (my fingers just don't seem willing to hit a `(` after typing `print` :-)

Comment: @eryksun no, I'm hoping for a 3.x version that is much closer in speed to 2.7. Is that too unreasonable?

Comment: @thebjorn, profile the critical parts of your code in 3.x. I expect it's comparable overall. But some changes in 3.x do trade performance or increased footprint for features (e.g. 3.3's [flexible string](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393) implementation). Also consider other implementations. PyPy 3.x will internally retain the `int`/`long` [hybrid design](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2014/02/py3k-status-update-13.html) (Py3k status update #13).

Comment: @eryksun pypy, especially with the stm stuff, is indubitably the right way forward -- but not quite ready for prime time yet. Meanwhile, 2.x end-of-life is rapidly approaching... :-(

Answer (score 3):

Apart from more precise timing, that Martijn Pieters suggests, one reason might be the humble `/`, whose [definition changed](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch05s06.html) between Python versions:

Python 2.7:

```
>>> 5/2
2
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 5/2
2.5
```

Python 3.0:

```
>>> 5/2
2.5
>>> 5//2
2
```

Re-try your timing with the `from __future__` statement for the Python 2 case.

Comment: When coding Python, you should always remember: “No-one expects the Spanish Inquisition!”

Comment: Hashing the 'if' clause (with the only /) results in the same timings so it must be something else.

Comment: Integer square roots are included in the range because of the +1. Integer factors are 'mirrored' above the square root hence the 'if' clause but the condition prevents integer square roots from being double counted. There was a previous Euler problem that used these ideas.

Comment: I also tend to think, that @Daniel's answer might explain the difference better. (I haven't done any tests though.)

Answer (score 2):

The Python3 int type was formerly the Python2 long type. Longs are slower than ints. Python is optimized for simplicity not speed.

Comment: @thebjorn [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers)

Comment: @JanneKarila that points to http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/ which (in the Transition section) says that the only issue left for Python 3 was the trailing `L` in the long representation. I.e. the int/long split is fixed in Python 2.7 (the same way that it is in 3, IIUC).

Comment: @thebjorn I was trying to point to *"Essentially, long renamed to int. That is, there is only one built-in integral type, named int; but it behaves mostly like the old long type."* Python 2.7 still has two integer types, and promotes an `int` automatically to `long` when necessary.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.2/whatsnew/3.0.html#performance says _The net result of the 3.0 generalizations is that Python 3.0 runs the pystone benchmark around 10% slower than Python 2.5. Most likely the biggest cause is the removal of special-casing for small integers. There’s room for improvement, but it will happen after 3.0 is released!_

Comment: +1: I modified the function for the 2.x test to use `long` integer constants (e.g. `501` -> `501L`), and the run time is 1.84 times longer.